# Test application on iPod with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, testing, publish

How can I put my incomplete application on my iPod before I publish it on the appstore? So I want to test it on my iPod.

Answer (score 2):

This requires a provisioning profile and developer identity. These things are available via the provisioning portal and requires a paid developer program membership.

You must generate an identity (by means of a certificate, and signing request) with keychain, and use the provisioning portal to upload the CSR and get a signed certificate matched to the identity. With this identity downloaded and installed, you'll use it to sign your binaries.

Applications have a unique bundle identifier. Using the provisioning portal, you must create a development provisioning profile associated with your device ID(s). Download and install the provisioning portal, and you should be set to build and run on your device.

The provisioning portal has concise steps to walk you through this process..

developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action

Answer (score 0):

You have to have a provisioning profile and if you do you have to do some things in the account which you then put in xcode and transport it to the iPhone